# Align text in center of Bootstrap Nav Bar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'd like to move the link 'Getting started' to the middle of the navbar, rather than aligned to the left. How do I do this?

[My jsFiddle is here](http://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/4934/).

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Bootstrap 3</a>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-center">
                <li class="dropdown active">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Getting started <b class="caret"></b></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#download">Download Bootstrap</a></li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li class="dropdown-header">Examples</li>
                        <li><a href="http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#template">Basic template</a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://getbootstrap.com/examples/starter-template/">Starter template</a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/">Grids</a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://getbootstrap.com/examples/jumbotron/">Jumbotron</a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar/">Navbar</a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://getbootstrap.com/examples/signin/">Sign-in page</a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://getbootstrap.com/examples/sticky-footer/">Sticky footer</a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://getbootstrap.com/examples/offcanvas/">Offcanvas</a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://getbootstrap.com/examples/carousel/">Carousel</a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://getbootstrap.com/examples/theme/">Theme</a></li>                        
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li class="dropdown-header">Compatibility</li>
                        <li><a href="http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#migration">Migrating from 2.x to 3.0</a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#browsers">Browser support</a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#third-parties">Third party support</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li class="active"><a href="http://getbootstrap.com/customize">Customize</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="jumbotron">
        <h1>Twitter Bootstrap 3.0</h1>
        <p class="lead">Starter template with CSS and JS included.</p>
        <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#fork">Fork this fiddle</a></p>
      </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can center adding `text-align:center` to the containing parent navbar and setting the navbar you want to center to `display:inline-block` and removing the `float:left`:

```
.navbar-default{
  text-align:center;
}
.navbar-center{
   display: inline-block;
   float: none; 
}
```

Adjusted [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/4939/)

Answer (score 0):

Change in css as defind in fiddle

```
.navbar-default .navbar-brand{
 width: 100%;
 text-align: center;
 }
```

[Please try this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/4937/)

Answer (score 0):

You can actually do it in a bunch of ways.

**Solution 1:**

One of them is to give your `.navbar-brand` a `width` of 100% and `text-align: center` like this:

```
.navbar-brand{
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/4940/)

The solution would work but has a downside as the brandname would take up all the space on the `.navbar` and you wouldn't be able to put a `menu` in there.

**Solution 2:**

Another solution is to give the `.navbar-brand` a fixed `width`. Having a fixed `width` allows us to use `margin: 0 auto;` which would center the `div` without taking up all the space like *Soltuion one*. But that's not all. You also have to give `.navbar-header` a `width`of 100% and `position: absolute;` to make sure the menu items will be visible like this:

```
.navbar-header{
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
}
.navbar-brand{
    width:142px;
    margin:0 auto !important;
    display:block;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/4941/)

*The upside* of this solution is that you can use a menu on the same line as your brand, which would be possible with *Solution 1*.

*The downside* is that you have to give your brand a fixed `width`, which decreases the flexibility of the content in it.